# HTML How to switch through pages inside single file

Tags: html

I am making a webpage.

I created a button, which you click to get to another page.

Problem: I have to recreate the .HTML file and load it with `<a href="contact.html" style="text-decoration:none">Contact<br></a>`

but contact.html is just index.html with contact details.

So could I make a button that loads the new page without creating many .html files that display more text

source: https://github.com/4u7157/4u7157.github.io

Comment: Please provide a [mre] **on this site** that demonstrates the issue. It sounds like you're asking how to create a single page app, but maybe you want to have all of your content in a single HTML file for some reason.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I want all content in a single file because it literally just displays text. https://github.com/4u7157/4u7157.github.io/blob/master/index.html#L26 on this line I tried and https://github.com/4u7157/4u7157.github.io/blob/master/index.html#L64 here I called it. but all just gets displayed on default page https://4u7157.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use bootstrap and do this:

```html
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#contact" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="contact">
    Expand/collapse
</a>
<div id="contact" class="collapse">
    Here's the content you want to show while not creating many files.
</div>
```

Comment: its not working. its showing everything always. have a look https://4u7157.github.io/

Comment: @John Bielowski, will get back to you sunday evening. Maybe someone else solves it. Otherwise I will download your website and look